# Google Ad Manager API-Availability forecast results are not matching with the Google Ad manager UI forecast when CustomTargeting is set

Tags: java, api, forecasting, google-ad-manager

In the java code for forecasting the availability of a prospective line item , the below piece of code is used for Custom Targeting and the forecasted availability is not matching with the GAM UI forecast when the same set of targeting is used.

```
  CustomCriteria customCriteria = new CustomCriteria();
   long customTargetingKeyId = 11975183;
   customCriteria.setKeyId(customTargetingKeyId);
   long [] customTargetingValueIds = {448353925185L};
   customCriteria.setValueIds(customTargetingValueIds);
   
   CustomCriteriaSet customCriteriaSet = new CustomCriteriaSet();
  
   customCriteriaSet.setLogicalOperator(CustomCriteriaSetLogicalOperator.AND);
   customCriteriaSet.setChildren(new CustomCriteria[] {customCriteria});
   
   targeting.setCustomTargeting(customCriteriaSet);
```

How can I make this work and get the same forecast as in GAM UI ?